# Continuous population models

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to find all equilibria and determine which are asymptotically stable.

> \begin{align}
> x' &= rx\left(1 - \left(\frac xK\right)^\theta\right)\quad (0<\theta<1)\tag 1\\
> x' &= x\left(re^{1-\frac xK}-d\right) \tag 2
> \end{align}

(where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are separate problems.)

So can someone please help me?

Comment: To find equilibria, set $x' = 0$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: In equation (1) the equilibria are x=0 and x=K. about stability of equilibrium 0, f'(0)=r>0  so x=0 instable. then about stability of equilibrium K, f'(K)=-(\theta /K )<0  so x=K asymptitocally stable.

Comment: Can someone please help me?